# Is it possible to start some activity without opening it?

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I have a splash screen and an activity(A1). In A1 I download data from internet. I want to start downloading this data from Splash itself. Splash stays for 5 seconds after which it starts A1, so what I want is, start downloading data from Splash. If it is not downloaded in 5 seconds, A1 will show a progress Dialog(which it already does while downloading data) and if it completes download in those 5 seconds A1 will show that data(which it already does).

Any clean way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't get the connection with the title

Comment: Then use a timer... for 5 second in your spash

Comment: You need to make AsyncTask class on splash screen and download code is put it on that. Execute the Asynctask class on onCreate(). If some issue regarding downloading or internet connection then put code for check network connection in asynctask which has onPreExecute().

Comment: @blackbelt - If it is, I will start A1 immediately instead of waiting for 5 seconds and open it after 5 seconds.

Comment: start a service in splash screen and download your data over there, and then check for download data in your A1 activity, if its downloaded show your data or display a progress bar.

Comment: @Jack - I know about it, but the thing is, this Asyntask status has to be shared by Spash as well as A1(incase data is not downloaded in 5 seconds, A1 has to continue download data and show progress dialog), how to do it?

Comment: So one way for do it same thing, use timmer object in AsyncTask class and check it out if time is >5 second then open the alert dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I think, there is no need trying to "hack" android system. `Activity` is a system component which has visual representation.
So, I think you can do:

1) start `Service` in which you are downloading data. Service doesn't have visual representation.

2) Create `Activity` disguised as splash screen and load data with `AsyncTask` or `Loader`, providing some visual feedback to user.

Answer (score 0):

Use service to download your data from internet.
You can invoke the service from splash screen activity.

then you can use your downloaded data in any activity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could start a service that downloads your data while the splashscreen is on, and upon completion, that's the only time you remove the splash screen.

If the download fails, proceed to the next screen with some button or handler on how you want to handle the failed download.